# Why can [ -x file ] be false even after chmod 777 file?

Tags: bash

I'm an italian student trying to study bash. I have a question. I've to solve this following bash script

```
#!/bin/bash

echo hello

if [ -x "$namefile" ] ; then
  echo "file $namefile exists"
else
  echo " file $namefile doesn't exists"
fi
```

Reading your posts I understand that -x means if the file exists and is executable is true.
Now I have created a file with all permissions for all with `chmod 777 file` and I try to launch the script but the result is "File doesn't exists". Why?

This is a reverse engineering exercise and I can't modify the script.

Comment: Where is the variable `$namefile` being set?

Comment: i mean is a parameter because is not set. Writing on the shell I wrote ./sestoscr file to set it

Comment: Is `sestoscr` the name of the above script? If so, just executing it will not set the variable `$namefile`. Is `file` an argument that you gave to `sestoscr`? If so, that will be available in `$1` not `$namefile`.

Comment: sestoscr is the name of the script. then after space I set the parameter of the variable

Comment: Then it will be available in `$1`, not `$namefile`. You can however do `namefile="$1"` inside the script to assign the value to `namefile`.

Comment: Ok... but this is an reverse engineering exercise and I can't modify the script. How I can do?

Comment: Run it like this instead: `namefile=file ./sestoscr` - that's all on one command line

Comment: You could set `namefile` into the environment of the script, i.e. `namefile=myfile.txt sestoscr`. BTW, about wording: `-x` is not an option of the `if` command (which does not have "options"), but an argument of the `[`  command.

Comment: now I try this one but still doesn't work. The script also tell me the file doesn't exists

Comment: To repeat what user1934428 just said: `-x` is not part of `if`, it's part of `[`. You can use `if` without `[`, and you can use `[` without `if`.

Comment: Well, then it doesn't exist (or isn't executable by the current user). If you do `ls -l file` what does it show?

Comment: (doesn't exist, _or_ isn't executable by the current user)

Comment: BTW, `chmod 777` should never be run, by anyone, at all, under any circumstances. It lets _every user on your machine_, including completely untrusted accounts like `nobody`, modify a file that's also executable! It's not okay even as a temporary or troubleshooting measure -- for all you know there could be unprivileged malware waiting for such an opening to infect or replace executables.

Comment: Also, note that it's possible for a filesystem to be mounted `noexec`, such that files on it aren't executable even if permissions would otherwise allow them to be.

Comment: Either way, for this to be answerable, we need to be able to see it ourselves. Consider trying to build a reproducer in an online sandbox like https://repl.it/, so you can test that you're providing everything needed for someone else to observe what's going on and test a proposed fix.

Comment: Nitpick - or a sign of a bigger problem than the one we're trying to help you solve: The output you claim to get, `File doesn't exists`, does not match anything inside the script. Are you sure you are running the script in the question?

Comment: (if you aren't setting `namefile` in the environment, that's certainly the easiest explanation)

Comment: `bash -x yourscript` is also a good place to start to get trace-level logging.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I know but is just for trying, I also can type chmod +x file.

Comment: Once again, please [edit] your question to show the output of `namefile=file bash -x sestoscr` (all run as one command / on one line).

Comment: And yes, `chmod +x file` is what you should do instead of `chmod 777 file`. Though since you _already_ did `chmod 777`, something like `chmod 755 file` is more appropriate to turn off g+w and o+w.

Comment: And when I said "for any purpose", _any_ purpose includes "just for trying". Unless you did the work to set up a virtual machine you can roll back or destroy, weakening system security even just for testing is a Very Bad Idea.

Comment: I solve the problem thanks to you, the right answer is this script doesn't go because I can't insert the value of "namefile". This is the answer my tutor wanna ear :)

Comment: _"this script doesn't go because I can't insert the value of "namefile"."_ - That's not correct. If you run the above script like this: `namefile=file ./bash -x sestoscr` then `namefile` _will_ be set to `file` inside the script. You could edit your question and put the output of that command in the question if you still claim it doesn't work. You also never showed what the output of `ls -l file` is so we can see for how that looks.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to modify your script, set the variable when calling the script:

```
namefile=myfile.txt ./sestoscr
```

(assuming that *sestoscr* is the name of the script you posted, and that the script has execute permission, and that *myfile.txt* is the name of the file you want to test using your script).

A more flexible solution would be to change the test in your script to

```
if [ -x "${namefile:=$1}" ] ; then
```

This still allows you to invoke the script via a change in environment (as outline above), but you also can call it using an explicit parameter,

```
./sestoscr myfile.txt
```

However, in this case I would give the positional parameter priority over the environment (because this is what most users would expect), and write it as:

```
namefile=${1:-$namefile}
if [ -x "$namefile" ]; ...
```

With this approach, if a parameter is supplied, it uses the parameter, and if none is supplied, it uses the environment variable `namefile`.